# How to get a sequence of letters between two letters

Tags: c#, unicode, char

This is how I can get the sequence of English letters between two letters, but it works only for English. Somebody know how can I do the same thing, but for Russian alphabet. Should I somehow use Unicode representations? If you did something similar, please, let me know here.u

```
        public static int aMatrixDim = 10;
        public static byte aFirstChar = (byte) 'a';
        public static byte aLastChar = (byte) 'z';
        public static int aCharsCount = aLastChar - aFirstChar + 1;

        public PatternsCollection CreateTrainingPatterns(Font font)
        {
            var result = new PatternsCollection(aCharsCount, aMatrixDim*aMatrixDim, aCharsCount);
            for (var i = 0; i < aCharsCount; i++)
            {
                var aBitMatrix = CharToBitArray(Convert.ToChar(aFirstChar + i), font, aMatrixDim, 0);
                for (var j = 0; j < aMatrixDim*aMatrixDim; j++)
                    result[i].Input[j] = aBitMatrix[j];
                result[i].Output[i] = 1;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: A `char` is not a `byte`, but a `short`

Comment: The more general solution is harder than you might think. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472692/how-to-get-all-characters-within-a-certain-utf-8-language-group for an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch Cryllic capital characters (Range 0410 to 042F) in a `List<char>`:

```
char CRYLLIC_CAPITAL_START = '\x0410';
char CRYLLIC_CAPITAL_END = '\x042F';

List<char> cryllicCapitalCharacters = new List<char>();
for (char c = CRYLLIC_CAPITAL_START; c <= CRYLLIC_CAPITAL_END; c++)
{
    cryllicCapitalCharacters.Add(c);
}
```

Or alternatively using **Linq**:

```
cryllicCapitalCharacters = Enumerable.Range('\x0410', '\x042F' - '\x0410' + 1)
                                     .Select(x => (char)x).ToList();
```

To do the same for small letters, use `0430` to `044F`

Russian Unicode Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode

Answer (score 1):

Unicode defines [32 out of 33](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode#Basic_Cyrillic_alphabet) Russian alphabet letters as consecutive ranges 
from `0x0410` to `0x042F` (for capital letters) and from `0x0430` to `0x044F` (for small letters). The missing letter [`Ё`/`ё`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode#Cyrillic_extensions) has the codes `0x0401`/`0x0451`.

So to build a list of Russian letters you may iterate through that ranges and add the missing `Ё`/`ё`. Additional sort operation is required if you need the letters to be ordered alphabetically:

```
var russianSmall = Enumerable.Range(0x0430, 32)
    .Concat(new[] { 0x0451 })
    .Select(i => Convert.ToChar(i))
    .ToList();

var russianSmallOrdered = russianSmall
    .OrderBy(c => c.ToString(), StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"), false))
    .ToList();

var russianCapital = Enumerable.Range(0x410, 32)
    .Concat(new[] { 0x0401 })
    .Select(i => Convert.ToChar(i))
    .ToList();

var russianCapitalOrdered = russianCapital
    .OrderBy(c => c.ToString(), StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"), false))
    .ToList();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NrcAUy